# Managed Bean Property Missing

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, managed-bean

```
type: Exception report

message: description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: /SSCPageMapping.jsp(39,5) '#{UpdateSSCPageMap.pageMap}' Property 'pageMap' not found UpdateSSCPageMap
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:277)
org.apache.myfaces.component.html.util.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:122)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)

root: cause org.apache.jasper.el.JspPropertyNotFoundException: /SSCPageMapping.jsp(39,5) '#{UpdateSSCPageMap.pageMap}' Property 'pageMap' not found on type UpdateSSCPageMap
org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:104)
javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:614)
javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1129)
javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:451)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:77)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:813)
javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:967)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:928)
javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:148)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.doRenderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:266)
com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:197)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
org.apache.myfaces.component.html.util.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:122)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

This is the HTTP 500 Error I received.  A collegue and I spent about an hour troubleshooting the unmapped managed bean property that can't be found although the following is confirmed:

1. Verified bean property names; renamed; and verified again
2. faces-config.xml has proper definitions including the manage bean properties
3. The Java code has been checked, double checked, triple checked.

Neither of us could determine the root cause preventing the bean class from being registered with the jsp page.  The jsp page was verified and it appears there is something very minor that was missed.

Within the faces-config.xml file it has highlighted that the bean properties can't be found.  How is this possible?

If you can suggest any place to look for further verification I would appreciate it.

Comment: Check if you have a managed bean called `UpdateSSCPageMap` or if you set an attribute in any scope (page, request, session, application) using this name.

Comment: check that you have a correct getter/setter for your property pageMap : getPageMap() the getter .

Comment: @Mifmif That was the problem; Accessor and Mutator for bean properties were not named getPageMap()/setPageMap(). I am still getting warnings within my faces-config.xml such as `Bean property pageId not found on parent class SSCPageMapBean`.

Comment: Try post your java class for more information. Did you try saw your getters for the property pageMap in the UpdateSSCPageMap class ?

Comment: Apart of not having the right getters and setters for your fields (which is basic knowledge for Java and JSF development), do not forget **to not** have any business logic in your getter/setter methods...